# How to find the length of itertools.izip_longest

Tags: python

i have many tuples stored within a 'itertools.izip_longest'

i am trying to loop through these tuples contained withinthe itertools.izip_longest to alter some values as shown in the code below

```
for i in range(len(pixels)):
  if i >= 2148 and i <= 3505:
    if pixels[i][0] == 146: # assuming each data element is a 3 element tuple
     pixels[i][0] += 1
```

however when i try to run the code, i get an error relating to the length :

```
  for i in range(len(pixels)):
TypeError: object of type 'itertools.izip_longest' has no len()
```

how can i find the length (number of tuples) contained within the itertools.izip_longest

thanks

Comment: It can be infinitely long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you cannot, because it's a generator. Upon call for an element it is generated on the fly. This allows to make things more dynamic, and use less memory in certain cases. In case of zipping you don't generate a copy of the lists, but generator generates tuples on the fly.

However, you can use it to insantiate something that has `len` like a list:

```
pixels = list(pixels)
```

What this does is it consumes generator and makes a list under the same name. (After generating the list generator would be consumed, so there is no point in leaving it around.) Please remember it's a slightly different object, and it is not always suitable performance wise. Usually it is possible to compute and store the number of elements before zipping with out creating additional objects.

Btw why won't you just iterate over pixels that you need to?

```
pixels = list(pixels)
for pixel in pixels[2148:3505]:
  if pixel[0] == 146:
    pixel[0] += 1
```

Now you are doing 2148 iterations that are guaranteed to do nothing.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a better solution, the idea is to add 1 to a pixel value of 146 to make it 146,however when run i get the error TypeError: 'itertools.izip_longest' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: That is because of the same reason. The elements don't exists in generator, so you cannot randomly get 2148th. `pixel` is assumed to be a list already. I edited the answer so it includes the line.

Answer (score 2):

`izip_longest` returns a [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators), where each item returned is generated on the fly.  If you want to know how many items are in the iterable, you can do

```
len(list(pixels))
```

This is the same as

```
len([item for item in pixels])
```

Example:

```
In [1]: from itertools import izip_longest

In [2]: x = izip_longest(range(10), range(100))

In [3]: len(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e62f33f06233> in <module>()
----> 1 len(x)

TypeError: object of type 'itertools.izip_longest' has no len()

In [4]: len(list(x))
Out[4]: 100
```